# SELECT From same table with 2 condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table here :

```
id     | Productid     | Productname
1        1               Test1
2        1               Test2
3        0(Null)         Test3
4        0(Null)         Test4
5        2               Test5
6        2               Test6
```

Note : Productid field is nullable in my database structure

What i want for result is

```
id     | Productid     | Productname
1        1               Test1
2        1               Test2
3        0(Null)         Test3
4        0(Null)         Test4
```

I want to SELECT from table with productid = 1 AND 0(Null)

Thanks for any replies

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about rudimentary SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE Productid=1
  OR Productid IS NULL
```